# Don't override primary key, only generate random string by Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, primary-key

I've installed ruby gem https://github.com/melcher/has_public_id 
Anytime I have used it - it override my ID.
Of course, this is correct, but how to change this gem to have still my old ID?
Protect override my ID.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward in the Usage section of the gem.

Does not seem to *override* the `id` column as you described either.

There are similar gems and non override `id`.

> Add an additional identifier column. I called it "ident", but call it whatever you want.

```
User.find_by_public_id(params[:id])
```

https://github.com/melcher/has_public_id#usage

Comment: Problem is disabling this functionality. When I change ident to id, my id's will be changed to random strings. No option to disable it. I need this gem to generate random string for specific row in db, but not override identifier.

Comment: Again I don't really follow. You want to a new identifier and id, this is what the gem does. Don't do `has_public_id :id`, create a new column instead.

Comment: I want only generate string a-z,A-Z,0-9 for one row in db, no changing about ID. Just generating it. This mean disable override ID in this gem. When I try use it, (:ident) or whatever else used will be primary key.

Comment: Wtf are you trying to do exactly? And why isn't your question about THAT?